# How to scale the tip of a curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, vertices, geometry, curve-modifier

I am trying to model a screw, but I need the tip to end in a small, fine point (almost Scale 0), how can I achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Edit* mode select the vertex and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, you can also type the radius in the *N panel > Item > Transform > Radius*, or right click > *Set Curve Radius*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! that solved a lot! is there any way to make the tip 'round'?

Comment: no, unless you create several vertices and reduce their radius so that it looks round, but if you convert to mesh you'll be able to round the tip much more easily